# How to insert json data into mysql using node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, server

```
var express = require('express');
var app=express();
var length;
var affiliate = require('flipkart-affiliate');
var url = require('url');
var moment=require('moment');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var body;
var getUrl;
var product;
var offer;
var offer1;
var offer2;
var offer3;
var test1;
var test2;
var test3;
var title=[];
var description=[];
var startTime=[];
var endTime=[];
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: '',
    database: 'coupontest'
});
var client = affiliate.createClient({
    FkAffId: 'anandhkum',
    FkAffToken: 'eb030998c556443087d3b1a27ac569d0',
    responseType: 'json'
});
client.getCategoryFeed({
    trackingId: 'anandhkum'
}, function(err, result,getUrl){
    if(!err){
        body=JSON.parse(result);
        getUrl=body.apiGroups.affiliate.apiListings.food_nutrition.availableVariants["v1.1.0"].get;
        client.getProductsFeed({
            url: getUrl
        }, function(err, result){
            if(!err){

            }else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        });
    }
});
connection.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) {
        return console.error('error: ' + err.message);
    }
    console.log('Connected to the MySQL server.');
});
app.get('/',function (req,res) {
    client.getAllOffers(null,function(err, resp){
        if(!err){
            offer=JSON.parse(resp);
            test1=offer.allOffersList.length;
            res.send(offer);
            for(var i=0;i<test1;i++){
                description[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].description;
                startTime[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].startTime;
                endTime[i]=offer.allOffersList[i].endTime;
            }
            var stmt = "INSERT INTO offers (description,start_time,end_time) VALUES ?";
            connection.query(stmt, [description,startTime,endTime], function (err, result) {
                if (err) throw err.message;
                console.log("Number of records inserted: " + result.affectedRows);
            });
        }
        else{
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
});
app.listen(3000);
console.log("Listening to port 3000");
```

I'm getting the error

```
 throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^
ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' 3 ports - multi device charging', 'Universal Voltage', 'Best Price Ever', 'Ext' at line 1
```

Answer (score 1):

When doing a prepared statement, you need a `?` for each of the values you bind. E.g. `INSERT INTO offers (description,start_time,end_time) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)`

It might be worthwhile to take a look at using something like the knex.js module. It uses the mysql module underneath and does the sql binding under the hood.